Get-MgGroupMember by user search - need help on array match
I'm having a PowerShell syntax issue: I can't seem to match members of one array to another array, but I can confirm the members exist in both arrays.  Can someone point out my logic error?
Background:
I want to search Entra for all members of a specific group, based on a search string of the member's properties (e.g. DisplayName and Surname).  Given limitations to the Get-Mg* -filter calls, I've come up with this approach:
$groupName = 'staff'            # all results should be in staff group
$userMatchString = 'Be'         # e.g. [Be]n Smith, Jim [Be]am...
$domainMatch = 'example.com'    # custom domain - no Entra guests

## choose a central M365 group filter
$group = get-mggroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($groupName)'"
$groupMemberIds=Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $group.id  -ConsistencyLevel eventual -All | select Id

## find Entra users matching a search string
## Due to graph filter limitations we do separate calls per attribute
$userMatches=@(Get-MgUser -ConsistencyLevel eventual -Count userCount -Filter "startsWith(DisplayName, '$($userMatchString)')" | where { $_.Mail -like "*@$($domainMatch)"})

$userMatches+=@(Get-MgUser -ConsistencyLevel eventual -Count userCount -Filter "startsWith(Surname, '$($userMatchString)')" | where { $_.Mail -like "*@$($domainMatch)" })

At this point $groupMemberIds contains every qualifiable person to search for and $userMatches contains every Entra search result (that may or may not be in the group).
This confirms (for my resultset) that the first record is already a match: $groupMemberIds | where { $_.Id -eq $userMatches[0].Id }
Can someone help me with syntax for (any userMatches ) in (groupMemberIds)?
This doesn't work - it returns 'false' for all of them:
$userMatches | ForEach-Object { $($_.Id -in $groupMemberIds) }
Any ideas?  Thanks!
UPDATE:
With my code I'm apparently comparing string to PSCustomObject... trying to figure out how to compare these as apples to apples...
$userMatches[0].Id.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object

$groupMemberIds[0].gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object


In order to compare these apples to apples, I need to specify the .id property of the array members versus the array members themselves.
This version with $groupMemberIds.id is returning matches, as it is now a String comparison:
$userMatches | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Id -in $groupMemberIds.id) { 
        "{0} was found in {1}" -f  $_.DisplayName,$groupName 
        }
    }


I'm unsure as to which limitation you're referring to but what it seems you're looking to achieve is certainly doable through the OData filter. I'm not sure if you can do it with the Get-MgGroupMember cmdlet but using Invoke-MgGraphRequest you can do:
$groupName = 'staff'            # all results should be in staff group
$userMatchString = 'Be'         # e.g. [Be]n Smith, Jim [Be]am...
$domainMatch = 'example.com'    # custom domain - no Entra guests

$group = Invoke-MgGraphRequest GET "v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName eq '$groupName'"
$groupId = $group.value.Id
$uri = "v1.0/groups/$groupId/members?`$filter=startsWith(displayName, '$userMatchString') and endsWith(mail, '$domainMatch')&`$count=true"

$result = do {
    $response = Invoke-MgGraphRequest GET $uri -Headers @{
        ConsistencyLevel = 'eventual'
    }
    $uri = $response.'@odata.nextLink'
    if ($response.value) {
        $response.value
    }
}
while ($uri)

# do stuff with result
$result | Select-Object id, displayName, mail


Thanks - it's definitely me: I'm comparing PSCustomObject to string and I can't figure out how to convert it to do the comparison :(

@tb1 you've already found the answer to your question. this answer is just to show that there is a more efficient way to get the information using the graph filter

Your examples are always a pleasure though - I learn a lot of new approaches and proper syntax :D

There's a much easier approach. When you use Get-MgGroupMember you will retrieve all the user properties you need to do your filtering. But your script is stripping these values when you pipe your output to | Select id.
You can do it like this:
$groupName = 'staff'            # all results should be in staff group
$userMatchString = 'Be'         # e.g. [Be]n Smith, Jim [Be]am...
$domainMatch = 'example.com'    # custom domain - no Entra guests

## choose a central M365 group filter
$group = get-mggroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($groupName)'"
$groupMembers=Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $group.id -ConsistencyLevel eventual -All

## find Entra users matching a search string
## Due to graph filter limitations we do separate calls per attribute
$userMatches = $groupMembers | Where { `
    ($_.DisplayName -like "*$userMatchString*") -and `
    ($_.Mail -like "*@*$domainMatch*") `
}

# Show user matches
$userMatches | Select DisplayName,Mail | ft


Hmm.. true...  I was too caught up trying to speed up the results to realize I was being redundant. But in the Get-MgGroupMember each of those properties is nested within the AdditionalProperties property set, so we'd have to expand that out before the where filter, no?

Oh, yes. That's correct.

You've made me rethink my strategy here:  I wanted to get a fast result of users and then do a fast check if they are in the group.  The call I make to "Get-MgGroupMember" has to pull the entire group's memberlist and metadata before I can compare the few people I'm checking against.  There's another call "Confirm-MgUserMemberGroup" that does a 1:1 check.  I'm going to write another answer that does this - even though it doesn't answer my original (silly) syntax, it's another arguably more efficient way to solve my problem.  Thanks for pointing out the redundancy!

@tb1 Let me know if API side filtering was able to help. I don't have insight in to the potential performance gains of specifying filter criteria when calling the API, but I suspect the backend is doing something very similar to what my example is doing, thus no benefits to performance. But it would be good to see your final solution.

That was a great question - I just ran all three in separate windows.  My original (post) version searches mguser, then mggroupmember: That finishes in 13 seconds.  Your version skips mguser (just expanding mggroupmember): That finishes in 10 seconds.  My last version searches mguser and Confirm-MgUserMemberGroup: That finishes in 6 seconds!  Confirm-MgUserMemberGroup seems to be a clear winner for the context I'm using.  I'm guessing it's indexed purely on ids so you're not pulling in all that extra metadata.  This was great, thanks so much!

Although my other answer solves the root question I had (comparing the arrays), this alternate answer is arguably a more efficient way to compare the results.  Kudos to Architect Jamie and Santiago Squarzon for their help!
Full example:
$groupName = 'staff'            # all results should be in staff group
$userMatchString = 'Be'         # e.g. [Be]n Smith, Jim [Be]am...
$domainMatch = '@example.com'   # custom domain - no Entra guests

## choose a central M365 group filter
$group = get-mggroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($groupName)'"

## find Entra users matching a search string
## Due to graph filter limitations we do separate calls per attribute
$userMatches=@(Get-MgUser -ConsistencyLevel eventual -Count userCount -Filter "startsWith(DisplayName, '$($userMatchString)')" | where { $_.Mail -like "*@$($domainMatch)"})
$userMatches+=@(Get-MgUser -ConsistencyLevel eventual -Count userCount -Filter "startsWith(Surname, '$($userMatchString)')" | where { $($_.Mail).EndsWith($domainMatch) })

## check 1:1 if the users we found are in our group.
## this call allows multiple groupID matching so it could be extended
## to filter if the user is in any vs all vs threshold amount of groups...
$usermatches | where { (Confirm-MgUserMemberGroup -UserId $_.Id -GroupIds @($group.Id)) }

